# Is there a way to get the c++ code after substitute all the head files and macros?

Tags: c++

I want to search the way a c++ library works, so I want to know the code after the maro and head files are substituted.

Comment: Yes. Try to search for "<your compiler name> preprocessor output"

Comment: If you're on a linux system (or have a shell and environment available), you can run CPP, the C preprocessor, from the command line and direct its output into a file. That should give you a decent insight into how it works.